# Jquery tabs is not working, what am i missing?

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I'm trying to use jquery tabs, i got the code from the site: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs and try it, look:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#tabs").tabs();
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
        <pre><code>$('#example').tabs();</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens. What am i missing?

Comment: @Ricksher - if you feel that any of the answers have helped you, please accept it. It is helpful for you too if you need to get good answers for your other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the css theme of jquery ui. Look [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started) ("Basic overview: using jQuery UI on a web page") for details. Put it in your head tag:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

You can choose the default theme or create you own theme via [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: If i want do my own css? What i have to do? With my colors and etc...?

Comment: Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ to create you own theme, or choose an example theme.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing stylesheet. Include  `<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">` before your javascript files

If you want to override a style, you can do the following. For example, if you want to change the text color of the active  tab, I see that the following classes were being used through chrome developer tools. So I can override these classes in my css

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited {
            color: red !important
}
```

Comment: If i want do my own css? What i have to do? With my colors and etc...?

Comment: if you want to change the text color of the tabs for example, you can override that particular class in your css file and can use !important so your style takes effect. You can always get the css style of a particular element by inspecting it in firebug (if you are using firefox) or chrome developer tools.

Comment: Alternatively, doesn't jquery ui have a them building tool on their website? You could use that to build a jquery ui compatible theme to match your current css.